# ADB Pull function

Tags: adb, pull

SO I am a newbie here , my phone's screen got broken yesterday but the phone itself is still working. I am trying to pull my data, like pics songs and stuff, out of the phone before sending it to be repaired.
adb recognizes the phone but when I enter the command pull /storage/sdcard0/

I get  pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped

I tried installing the syncdroid apk through adb but I get an error : failed to copy ........... no such file or directory

can anyone help me I really need the data on  my phone?

my phone is on SLimkat , I don't remember which build , It is an i9100G ( Galaxy S2)

and I am pretty sure it is working fine as I get notifications.

Debugging mode on apparently.

Comment: try http://qtadb.wordpress.com/download/ , generally your data should be in /sdcard

Comment: You can also use `adb shell` and navigate your phones file system to ensure your path is correct. Use `cd xxxx` to change directories and `ls` to get file listings.

Comment: I retrieved the path but still same problem

Comment: Try `adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to find the correct path.